# SharePoint 2013 - Allow anonymous search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using SharePoint 2013 OOTB, and can see that anonymous access to view the "entire site" is checked under site settings -> site permissions for anonymous users.

Why else would my search results web part not be displaying the same results on the page, that is shows when I do log in? It shows nothing when I am logged out.

I simply added the SharePoint search result web part from the ribbon, to my publishing page and gave it a custom search query.

Thanks for any advice on this

Comment: did you check the event viewer on the server and the ULS logs (in the "15 hive") to see if anything stands out (e.g. permission issues).?

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Yeah, I think I overlooked the document library settings, or didn't wait long enough after a full crawl and/or SharePoint reset to make the search recognize the one document library (when logged out), and the other (when logged in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try few steps give below?

1. Reset your search index and then do a full crawl. Click below to know how to reset search index.
   [Reset Search Index](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219652(v=office.15).aspx)
2. Disable lockdown feature on the site collection, disable anonymous access, then enable anonymous access again, full crawl of the website
3. Web part indexing

   - Under the SharePoint Site go to Site Settings.  Search Administration -> Search and offline availability -> Indexing ASPX Page Content, Enable the option "Always index all Web Parts on this site"
   - Under Search Service Application, do a Full Crawl for the content source to resolve this issue.

Comment: Also, I had to double check settings on each document library.  In my specific case, I have multiple document libraries storing documents. and I think I overlooked the document settings...Thanks

Comment: I also dropped a sharepoint search web part adn search results web part onto a publishing page.  With that said, I am depending on custom search queries to show my results from specific document libraries.  So that may also play a role in why things are working well now.