# Search is not working for anonymous users in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, search-results, anonymous-authentication, catalog

I have implemented search in my SharePoint 2013 site. It is returning an error as "Sorry Something went wrong" for anonymous users. I have also done full crawling for the site after enabling the anonymous access.

Comment: here is similar [thread](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130811/sharepoint-2013-allow-anonymous-search-results) . may be help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vishal.But this didn't work for me.I is returning the same thing as "Sorry something went wrong".Is there any other approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using custom managed properties, display templates, etc.?

Comment: I used custom managed properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to solve this issue by turning on anonymous search results cache, it's under "setting" in CSWP (you can configure it in CSWP or check the link below for more advanced tricks.)

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/anonymous-search-results-cache-sharepoint-2013-public-websites/

[Mar-28 Updated]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply YogaPanda. But I cannot open the URL what you have provided.

Comment: No worries, I believe you can google and find it. Attached the screenshot to my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If it works for logged in users and not for anonymous only then you have to run a powershell script that enables anonymous again for these lists.

I have written a blog post about this:

[SharePoint search not working for anonymous users](http://haithamshaddad.com/2016/03/22/sharepoint-2013-search-not-working-for-anonymous-users/)